# UIScrollView problems with parent view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, subview

I have a view that recognize horizontal pan gesture (Moves of the screen if you swipe it to the right) and a subview which is a UIScrollView that scroll vertically. The problem is that when I do a horizontal swipe the parent view no longer moves because the UIScrollView does not pass the touch to the parent view. All I want is when the user swipes horizontally the parent view moves of the screen and when the user swipes vertically the UIScrollview scrolls its content.

Comment: have you tried using swipe gesture instead of pan? it also seems to make more sense in your case

Comment: Going from memory here, but I think the scroll view has a property you can set to lock (prevent) horizontal scrolling. That might stop it from interfering with your gesture recognizer?